# Pass Component to a Component in Angular using Alias

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to pass server-element component to the app html but when I run it it shows me nothing

I have this server-element component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})

export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('srvElement') element: { type: string, name: string, content: string  };
  constructor() { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  }


}
```

sever-element html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">{{ element.name }}</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>
      <strong *ngIf="element.type === 'server'" style="color: red">{{ element.content }}</strong>
      <em *ngIf="element.type === 'blueprint'">{{ element.content }}</em>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the app component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverElements = [{type: 'server' , name: 'TestServer', content: 'Just a test!'}];



}
```

app html

```
<div class="container">  
<hr>  
<div class="row">  
<div class="col-xs-12">     
<app-server-element                      
   *ngFor=" let servetElement of serverElements"                         
[srvElement]="serverElement"></app-server-element>    
</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

the app module (I didn't change anything )

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';




import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CockpitComponent } from './cockpit/cockpit.component';
import { ServerElementComponent } from './server-element/server-element.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CockpitComponent,
    ServerElementComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I also different way of passing

server-element component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})

export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() element: { type: string, name: string, content: string  };
  constructor() { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  }


}
```

app html

```
<div class="container">  
<hr>  
<div class="row">  
<div class="col-xs-12">     
<app-server-element                      
   *ngFor=" let servetElement of serverElements"                         
[element]="serverElement"></app-server-element>    
</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

[[it should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0eDQ.jpg) ]
[[and I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkJtB.png) ]

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-12"> 
<ng-container *ngFor=" let servetElement of serverElements" >
<app-server-element                                             
[element]="serverElement"></app-server-element>
</ng-container>    
</div>`
Can you try something like this?

Comment: I don't know if it just a typo here in your stack, but you call your variable `let servetElement` while you use it as `serverElement` (used serve`t` instead of serve`r`)

Comment: Could you provide code on stackblitz?

Comment: Its a typo thank you for help! @W.S.

Answer (score 0):

just a typo  in (serverElement )

```
<div class="container">  
<hr>  
<div class="row">  
<div class="col-xs-12">     
<app-server-element                      
   *ngFor=" let serverElement of serverElements"                         
[element]="serverElement"></app-server-element>    
</div>  
</div>
</div>
```